# How to SSH to worker nodes of openshift cluster on IBM cloud

Tags: openshift, ibm-cloud, iks

I have a openshift cluster on IBM cloud. I want to connect to the worker nodes using SSH via Putty but documentation says,

```
SSH by password is unavailable on the worker nodes.
```

Is there a way to connect to those?

Comment: Are you referring to this documentation? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-cs_troubleshoot_clusters#cs_ssh_worker It says how to tackle it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use OpenShift v4 on IBM cloud, you may access your worker nodes using `oc debug node/<target node name>` instead of SSH. `oc debug node` command launches a temporary pod for the terminal session on the target node. You can check and run linux commands like usual SSH session through the Pod. Try it.

Comment: Thanks! This is something what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

SSH access to worker nodes in OpenShift is [disabled for security reasons](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-cs_ov#compare_ocp). [The documentation suggests to use DaemonSets for actions to be performed on worker nodes](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-cs_troubleshoot_clusters#cs_ssh_worker).